# Multiplying 2 Columns in Sum Function giving an error in Crystal Formula Shop?

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, formula, multiplication

SAP Crystal Formula Workshop detecting the error when I am trying to multiply two columns inside the SUM function. However, my logic is working absolutely fine in MS SQL. Following is my SQL Code:

```
select Sum(Qty * Type) from Movements
```

Where, type could be '1' or '-1'. I am using this statement to get the Balance. Following is my formula inside the crystal report formula shop which is giving an error:

```
SUM({MovementReport;1.Qty} * {MovementReport;1.Type})
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a separate formula field that multiplies the two columns:

```
{MovementReport;1.Qty} * {MovementReport;1.Type}
```

and then calculate the sum of that formula field:

```
SUM({@YourNewFormula})
```